# Is there a way to Make Database Table Name as Prefix of Database Table's Field Name

Tags: database, toad

Is there a way to Make Database Table Name as Prefix of Database Table's Field Name. For example: Say I have TABLE1 which has ID Column. I'd like to make the field name as TABLE1_ID or TABLE1ID instead of TABLE1.ID.

In other words is there a way to Qualify Field names?
Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible, because you're looking at the problem in the wrong way(whatever your problem is):
Your field name is ID and TABLE1.ID is how you access that field so when you say TABLE1.ID you can think of Field 'ID' from table 'TABLE1'.

Think about it like a class property and let's take an example in Python:

```
class someClass():
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.ID = id
TABLE = someClass(3)
print(TABLE.ID)
```

So I'm printing the ID of the TABLE and not the TABLE.ID

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am aware of that; however, I am asking a different question, you see I work with tools such as Qlik which has a property of "QUALIFY" and what qualify basically does is to merge the table name to the field name. I need this to be as an Alias field name. Any ideas?